# Find the index of each letter of a given string, and return the same index if the letter is repeated

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm trying to solve a fairly simple kata and find myself stuck to a conditional. I'm trying to return the same integer for a string that has the same letter more than once.

For example, for the string `hello` it should return `0.1.2.2.3`.

This is my code so far:

```
const wordPattern = word => {
  word = word.toLowerCase();
  let index =[]
  
  for(i=0; i<word.length; i++){
    index.includes(i) ? word(i) === index[i] : index.push(i)
  }
    
  return index 
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `0,1,2,2,4`?

Comment: Looks like a recruitment task or a practice (lesson) task and you have just asked for an answer. Have you tried to solved it yourself? What did you try? Where did you fail? Try to learn first.

Comment: Hi Adam, yes I did as you can see in my code above, and also yes, the testing examples should return 0,1,2,2,3.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an object, because it provides me the ability to map a key (the letter) to a value (the integer assigned to that letter):

```js
const wordPattern = word => {
  word = word.toLowerCase();
  const map = {}
  const output = []
  let counter = 0
  
  for(i=0; i<word.length; i++){
    if (!map[word[i]]) {
      map[word[i]] = counter
      counter++
    }
    output.push(map[word[i]])
  }
    
  return output 
}
```

You could also loop the string using for..of if you are using a modern enough javascript version (es6):

```js
const wordPattern = word => {
  word = word.toLowerCase();
  const map = {}
  const output = []
  let counter = 0
  
  for(const l of word) {
    if (!map[l]) {
      map[l] = counter
      counter++
    }
    output.push(map[l])
  }
  return output 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Mapping is a good approach, I didn't think about it!

Answer (score 1):

You can look ahead in loop with regular if statement

```js
const wordPattern = word => {
  word = word.toLowerCase();
  let index =[];
  // Because you don't want word letters index,
  // you can create separate index
  let c = 0;
  
  for(let i=0; i<word.length; i++){
    // Add c to index array
    index.push(c);
    // Increase c index
    c++;
    // Look ahead and do simple logic
    // by decreasing your c index if next
    // letter equals current
    if(word[i+1] && word[i+1] === word[i]) c--;
  }
    
  return index 
}

// Test
console.log(wordPattern('Hello').toString());
console.log(wordPattern('Success').toString());
```

Comment: Thank you tarkh! It really looks simple enough put it this way! Appreciate the time and explanation :)

Comment: Wellcome! If answer helps you, please accept it in settings ;)